# Best way to store OAuth token iOS?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0

I am writing an iOS app that uses [Twitch.tv's API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md) to allow my app to access their users content.  They use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication.  I need to use this access token every time I make a request to access a users info.

My question is where should I store it?

Should I make a class that has it as a property?  In that class I could also store my Redirect URI and Client_ID to keep things in one place.

I thought about NSUserDefaults, but I read it's not very secure.

What is the best design pattern for this approach on iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is worded you seem to be confusing the use of the word store to mean two entirely different things. If you use NSUSerDefaults then the token would be stored to file and would persist if the app is killed. If you make it a property of a class it is being temporarily stored in memory and would not persist if the app is killed. Your question is therefore asking should I use Apples or Oranges.

If you need persistent storage for sensitive data then you should not use NSUserDefaults, instead use the iOS keychain.Use of the keychain is a bit too lengthy to describe here.
The keychain is encrypted but only using the user's 4 digit pin code, which could potentially be brute forced cracked. So you could also potentially encrypt it.